# Spark app reading dynamic JSON field's value from JSON file

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark app attempting to read from several JSON files. Each file is represented something like. However, the special_field will have different key/values per file. It does not have a consistent schema.

```
{
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": 35,
    "special_field": {
        "my_field1": "abc"
        "my_field2": 12345
        "my_field3": "xyz"
    }
}
```

Code:

```
case class MyObject(name: String, age: Int, specialField: JSONObject)

val myDataFrame = spark.read.json(path = "s3://bucket/*.json")
      .select(properties.head, properties.tail: _*)    
      .map(line =>
        MyObject(
          name = line.getAs[String]("name"),
          age = line.getAs[Int]("age"),
          specialField = line.getAs[JSONObject]("special_field")
       )).toDF
```

Question is related to the field `special_field` in the JSON input file. It is dynamic in that the schema is unexpected. For example the key/values are not known ahead of time.

I'd like to read it in as a JSONObject if possible into the MyObject class. I tried the above but it appears to throw an exception unable to cast to Any. Is it possible to read this field's value as a JSONObject or anything similar?

Comment: Why you need Spark to read JSON? May be 1) read 2) convert to DF?

Comment: Oh the above is just an example, but I'll be processing thousands of json files and each will have multiple lines of json with other fields that require transformations

Comment: JSON format is incorrect: after each row (expect last) must be common. And second row is number, not String?

Comment: The special_field will have a different schema each time. Sometimes the key/values will be different

Comment: I'm interested in just taking special_field as a json object without having to deal with the Field's key/values

Comment: Can you fix JSON format at example?

Comment: Updated description in question

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with scala but mostly u can cast the JSonObject to JsonaArray and call an iterator on it and use map.entry interface to get the key and value

Comment: It is not array: the object has different keys and presents as object. How you can cast object to array?